# Why can JobScheduler be compliled when minSdkVersion is 15

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

In my mind,  JobScheduler is required Android 5.0 or above, now the following code can be complied, why?

I think that Android Studio 3.1.2 should diplay the information *minSdkVersion 21 is required* when I try to complie the code!

```
  private fun startScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){ 
        val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

        val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext.packageName, RestoreService::class.java.name))
                            .setPeriodic(interval)
                            .setPersisted(true)
                            .build()

        mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
    }
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    flavorDimensions "default"

    defaultConfig {      

        applicationId "info.dodata.mirror"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.05"
        archivesBaseName = "BackupSettings-V" + versionName
    }   
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Have you added any annotations above your method?

Comment: No any annotations

Answer (score 0):

No error because target versio is 26 that,s why is supporting. and min sdk version provides support to older version of android.The Android 5.0 Lollipop (API 21) release introduces a job scheduler API via the JobScheduler class. This API allows to batch jobs when the device has more resources available. In general this API can be used to schedule everything that is not time critical for the user.